# Card flip Javascript from more than one set

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, class, card-flip

I am making a card-flip game in javascript, and would like to be able to pull out different sets of cards.
In the data.js file I have 2 arrays, one for cards in one language, and one for cards in another:

```
const cardsItalian = [{
    name: "Cane Bianco",
    image: "cane.png",
    id: "cane"
  },

  {
      name: "Cane Bianco",
      image: "cane2.png",
      id: "cane2"
    },
```

There is also a const cardsSpanish.

In the game.js file, I can call the data from data.js, and I have the following at the bottom:

```
const startGame = (cards, level) => {

// reset game variables
    gameStarted = false;
    moves = 0;
    matches = 0;
    setLevel(level);

    // reset HTML
    $('#game-board').empty();

    $(".clock").text('0:00');
    $("#moves").text('0');
    $('#winModal').hide();

    // Get cards and start the game
    let cardArray = makeCardArray(cardsItalian, level);

    shuffle(cardArray);
    displayCards(cardArray);

  };
```

This code allows me to take the cards from cardsItalian array, or I can change it to cardsSpanish, however I am struggling to figure out how to do it for one or the other based on the user's selection! Driving me nuts.

I'm sure I could add a condition but I'm not sure where

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `prompt`.

```
var cards = prompt("Please select set. Type 1 for Italian or 2 for Spanish", "1 or 2");

if (cards ==1) 
let cardArray = makeCardArray(cardsItalian, level);
else if (cards ==2) 
let cardArray = makeCardArray(cardsSpanish, level);
else
//exit or call the function again till valid entry is made in prompt
```

**Warning :**

> Prompt creates dialogue box and will not show up if the user has blocked
>   dialogue box from appearing on the webpage. When dialogue box appears too often,
>   browsers provide an option to disable them.